# Не могу добавить в БД postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, spring-boot

Делаю через spring boot, БД создается, но когда добавляю информацию :

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into message (tag, text, id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select message0_.id as id1_0_, message0_.tag as tag2_0_, message0_.text as text3_0_ from message message0_
```

и ничего не добавляется.

проперти :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/message
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.pasword=root

spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.session.store-type=none
```

html файл :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="/logout" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Введіть повідомлення" />
                <input type="text" name="tag" placeholder="tag" />
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{_csrf.token}}"/>
                <button type="submit">Добавити</button>

            </form>
        </div>
        <div>Список повідомлень</div>
        {{#messeges}}
        <div>
            <b>{{id}}</b>
            <span>{{text}}</span>
            <i>{{tag}}</i>
        </div>
        {{/messeges}}
    </body>
</html>
```

Message.java :

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String text;
    private String tag;

    public Message() {
    }

    public Message(String text, String tag) {
        this.text = text;
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Контролер :

```
 @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting( Map<String, Object> model) {


        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String main(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(@RequestParam String text,
                      @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model) {

        Message message = new Message(text, tag);
        messageRepo.save(message);

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.put("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }
```

Ошибка :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.useContextualLobCreation(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl.makeLobCreatorBuilder(LobCreatorBuilderImpl.java:54) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.fSpring.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Метод org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob() ещё не реализован
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:683) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.createClob(PgConnection.java:1252) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Попробуй закомментировать `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` и `spring.jpa.generate-ddl`

Comment: НЕ допомогло...

Comment: Ошибок никаких нету?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null   в SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

Comment: Судя по ошибке у тебя что-то = `null`. Если хочешь, чтобы тебе помогли, прикрепи стек ошибки.

Comment: Прикрепил ошибку

Comment: Подскажите, решили ли вы данную проблему в итоге, если да , то каким образом?

Answer (score 1):

Без кода MessageRepo сложно судить, но я могу предположить, что Вы работаете вне транзакции. Метод `save()` вне транзакции не делает изменений в БД. Чтоб транзакция была, повесьте аннотацию `@Transactional` на метод контроллера, в котором у Вас происходит сохранение объекта. Также можно использовать метод `persist()` вместо `save()`.

Comment: Только `public interface MessageRepo extends CrudRepository<Message, Long>` , пробовал  `@Transactional ` не помогло. И кстате метода  `persist()` нету,  я правильно понял его нужно тут вьзьвать `messageRepo.persist()` ?

Comment: @FediaCholak нет не правильно. Нужно вызывать метод `save`.

Comment: А где использовать persist() вместо save() ? И Что еще может быть? Проблема осталась.

Comment: @FediaCholak метод persist() находиться в EntityManager (это когда используется чисто JPA API). Ты же используешь Spring Data JPA, так что тебе нужно использовать save().

Answer (score 1):

В application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: Попробывал оба варианта, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Проверил `Map<String, Object> model` там пусто

Comment: Поменяй `<form method="get">`

Comment: Поменял. Ошибка осталась

Comment: @FediaCholak посмотри в методе add(): text и tag != null? messages != null?

Comment: Когда `<form method="get">` не мог даже проверить. Поменял на `post` , и в `String text String tag`  информация есть, а в мап `model = null`  после добавления в нее.

Comment: Добавь в add() следующее: `Message saved = messageRepo.save(message);`    `if (saved.getId() == null) { Значит message в базу не сохранилось }`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80759/discussion-between-not-a-programmer-and-fedia-cholak).